# Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone exception not working

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Whenever I enter text in the outputText by clicking  speak out for the first time no exception happens, everything gets updated in the database but when I click the speak out button for the second time I get the following exception.

1) Home.xhtml

```
</div>
    <div style="width:100%;background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Speak Out"/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="Share whats in your mind.!" style="color:#aaaaaa;font-size:x-small;"/>
        <p:inputTextarea name="content" id="sharetext" cols="60" rows="2" onclick="this.value='';" value="#{statusBean.status.statusmsg}" style="text-size:small;" /><br/>

        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Speak Out"  action="#{statusBean.save}"  ajax="false" styleClass="buttonstyle"/><br/>
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Pic Out"/><br/>
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{statusBean.handleFileUpload}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Share whats in your mind through an image.!" style="color:#aaaaaa;font-size:x-small;"/>
        <p:inputTextarea name="content" id="sharetext" cols="60" rows="2" onclick="this.value='';" value="#{statusBean.status.picstatusdesc}" style="text-size:small;" /><br/>

        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Pic Out"  action="#{statusBean.picSave}"  ajax="false" styleClass="buttonstyle"/><br/>
    </h:form>   


    </h:panelGrid>
   </div>
```

2) StatusBean.java

```
    public class StatusBean {
Date d;
Comment comment;
Status status;
private EntityManager em;
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public Comment getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(Comment comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public StatusBean() {
    d = new Date();
    comment = new Comment();
    status = new Status();
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

public String save() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(true);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
    status.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    status.setStatusBy(user.getFirstName());
    status.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
    status.setPicture(user.getImage());
    System.out.println("status save called");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(status);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    session.isNew();
    return "success";
}

public String picSave() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(true);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
    status.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    status.setStatusBy(user.getFirstName());
    status.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
    status.setPicture(user.getImage());
    System.out.println("picstatus save called");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(status);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    session.isNew();
    return "success";
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent e) {
    System.out.println("file handler called");
    uploadedFile = e.getFile();
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(true);
    System.out.println(fileName);
    try {
        ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        String imagesPath = ctx.getRealPath("images");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagesPath
                + "/statusPicture/" + fileName);
        fos.write(uploadedFile.getContents());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        status.setPicstatus(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

3) Status Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class Status implements Serializable,Comparable<Status> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int statusId;
    private String email;
    private String picstatus;
    private String picstatusdesc;
    private String picture;
    private String statusBy;
    private String statusmsg;
    private long timeMillis;

    public Status() {
    }

    public int getStatusId() {
        return this.statusId;
    }

    public void setStatusId(int statusId) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPicstatus() {
        return this.picstatus;
    }

    public void setPicstatus(String picstatus) {
        this.picstatus = picstatus;
    }

    public String getPicstatusdesc() {
        return this.picstatusdesc;
    }

    public void setPicstatusdesc(String picstatusdesc) {
        this.picstatusdesc = picstatusdesc;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return this.picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getStatusBy() {
        return this.statusBy;
    }

    public void setStatusBy(String statusBy) {
        this.statusBy = statusBy;
    }

    public String getStatusmsg() {
        return this.statusmsg;
    }

    public void setStatusmsg(String statusmsg) {
        this.statusmsg = statusmsg;
    }

    public long getTimeMillis() {
        return this.timeMillis;
    }

    public void setTimeMillis(long l) {
        this.timeMillis = l;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Status o) {

        return (int) (o.getTimeMillis()-this.getTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

4) StackTrace

```
     WARNING: #{statusBean.save}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{statusBean.save}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at com.bean.StatusBean.save(StatusBean.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nullPrimaryKeyInUnitOfWorkClone(ValidationException.java:1439)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChanges(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChangesForExistingObject(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    ... 47 more

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [com.entity.Status@1523582], primary key [0]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nullPrimaryKeyInUnitOfWorkClone(ValidationException.java:1439)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChanges(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChangesForExistingObject(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at com.bean.StatusBean.save(StatusBean.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


log file rotation...
```

Comment: whats the scope of your status bean ?

Comment: and what's your primary key ?

Comment: my primary key is statusId. I just now included the status entity class above.

Comment: It's strange it's working on first call because it seems you do not set statusId and statusId is not annotated with an auto generated id. In fact it's more an eclipe link question than a JSF one

Comment: How do I annotate with an auto generated id. Actually I am new to JSF, it would be really helpful if you show me how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the [following link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey) eg. `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) private int statusId;`

Comment: the exception is now gone but the problem that I am now facing is that the previous data entry is getting overwritten.

Comment: You got an exception of `javax.persistence` package. You didn't got an exception of `javax.faces` package. You've a JPA problem, not a JSF problem. Please remove the JSF noise from the question and isolate the problem in JPA side by performing unit testing on it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why it works the first time, but just like Nicolas Labrot I can't see you setting your primary key and that is why you get an Exception that your primary key is `null`.
If you set your key somewhere else, check if it might be 0. Eclipselink does not support 0 as a primary key if you don't set the following property in your persistence.xml, you get that Exception.

```
<property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
```

This property simply tells EclipseLink to treat '0' as a valid primary key instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Property **eclipselink.allow-zero-id** is deprecated, so you should use **eclipselink.id-validation** to define which primary key components values are considered invalid.

```
<property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
```

See: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_id_validation.htm